# Are different WiFi chipsets manufactured for use as a station vs an AP?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, chipset

There's plenty of great low cost wireless routers in the market. But for D.I.Y. beginners it can be trial and error — based on anecdotes from Google/Amazon —— to see if an adapter will work as an AP using a common D.I.Y. setup like:

- Raspberry Pi
- [`hostapd`](https://w1.fi/hostapd/)
- [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)

In my case, I bought a decent USB adapter that technically could be used as an AP but was losing packets.

So — more generally — are different WiFi chipsets manufactured specifically for use as a station vs an AP? What capabilities — or specifications — would those have and should a D.I.Y.’er be on the look out for.

Comment: The capabilities of a given integrated circuit are based on the choices of the engineers who designed it. These are usually codified in the protocols the chip is designed to support.

Comment: A decent card (eg Intel) will support all modes properly. I don't think that AP functionality would be driven as much by the chipset as the firmware and drivers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are chips that are specifically targeted for use in an AP (note: what laypeople and marketers call a "wireless router" is an AP that includes router functionality), and there are chips that are specifically targeted for use in a wireless client station, and there are also chips that are designed to serve in either role.

If you browse the websites of the big Wi-Fi chipset manufacturers such as Broadcom, QCA (Qualcomm Atheros), Marvell, etc., you will see from the marketing information that some chips are more targeted for APs, some are more targeted for client stations, and some are marketed as being good for either role.

Chips designed for APs generally support more spatial streams (thanks to MU-MIMO), and since they're designed for devices that are stationary and always plugged into power, they are less likely to be that concerned with miniaturization, heat dissipation, and power consumption. They're also less likely to include integrated amplifiers, since AP engineers often like to select their own amps.

Most DIYers don't have the RF design/engineering chops and access to the necessary lab equipment to design and validate a good AP. The best you can hope for is to look for chipsets that the open source wireless driver/software community has had good luck with, and lean towards desktop PCIe cards, because those are less likely to be constrained by power/heat/size. The power/heat/size trade-offs used for chipsets for laptops and mobile and USB dongles are usually the opposite of the trade-offs you'd want for a good AP.

Comment: The last sentence really drove the point home.

Comment: _"(note: what laypeople and marketers call a 'wireless router' is an AP that includes router functionality)"_ This seems to be unnecessary denigration wrapped in pedantry; you just described the exact same thing in two terms that don't even substantially differ from one another.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No, there's a very substantial difference between an AP and a router. And "layman's terms" is a widely used expression which is only offensive if you're looking for a way to be offended.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev As Spiff pointed out, a wireless router _is_ an AP+router. By definition. Going out of your way to distinguish between these almost identical terms by calling out "laypeople" and "marketers" then adding scare quotes is just unnecessary lauding.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings By definition, the "fish and chips" dish is made of fish and chips, yet "fish" and "chips" are not identical. AP+router are just like that too, but less tasty.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Nobody said an AP is a router. ‍♂️ Ah well, ironically my F&C are here :) Cya

Comment: *Nobody said an AP is a router* - "you just described the exact same thing in two terms that don't even substantially differ from one another"

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings When I posted my Answer, there was a comment on OP's Question where someone had implied that a wireless router and an AP act differently at the 802.11 layer. So my parenthetical note was to bust that other myth that had been floating around this discussion. The mistaken commenter apparently got the message, and has since deleted the mistaken comment.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev We were talking about "wireless router" vs "an AP that includes router functionality". Which are the same. We were not talking about "AP" vs "router" ‍♂️

Comment: @Spiff Cool. :)